# Interfaces no longer work when using custom collection class

Tags: c#, list, collections, interface

I have created a class, `MonitoredCollection<T>`, that basically encapsulates/mimics List but allows me to fire events on certain calls.

Now however, whereever there is a parameter that takes a MonitoredCollection, where T is an Interface, I can no longer pass a `MonitoredCollection<T>` where T is a class that implements that interface, like I could with a `List`.

I always thought that interfaces were a language 'feature' and therefore I don't need to implement anything more to support this, so what have I missed?

EDIT: Sorry, I made a mistake in that question, as João correctly pointed out List never worked in this instance so the question is as it stands without that!

Comment: How have you defined the constraint on the collection class? Can we see some code?

Comment: Just as a side note; check out ObservableCollection<T> as it may provide your needed behavior already

Comment: Just as a comment, this answer by Eric Lippert blew my mind and might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923936/c-casting-a-generic-element-type-downwards

Comment: @Alex: Awesome link, great answer over there

Comment: @Alex, thank you for that link, that does make it much clearer.
@Mr. Disappointment, the collection class is declared as "public class MonitoredCollection<T> : IList<T>", no other constraints are present.
@Aaron, thanks for the suggestion, I will have a look at that as ill want my MonitoredCollection<> to take over where Lists & Events are concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a `MonitoredCollection<SomeObject>` instance, and you want to treat it as a `MonitoredCollection<ISomeInterface>` instance where `SomeObject` does in fact implement `ISomeInterface`. This does not create any problems for retrieving items from the collection, since object of type `SomeObject` can be converted to the interface type `ISomeInterface`.

However, for all the methods on your collection which modify the collection, such as those that assign a new value to an index, or insert a new item into the collection, this cast has created a whole suite of issues. I'd assume your `MonitoredCollection<SomeObject>` instance would have a method such as `Add(SomeObject obj)`, which would insert a new object into the collection. After the cast, the signature on this method would be `Add(ISomeInterface obj)`. This seems to make sense, but not all `ISomeInterface` objects are NECESSARILY `SomeObject` instances.

Because the casted object will allow operations on the collection that the original object wouldn't allow, the runtime won't allow this cast. C# 4.0 introduced covariance and contravariance to explicitly state what is valid for casts of this type, you can look into them for trying to solve this issue. However, you're really only going to have luck with a read only version of your collection (think `List<T>.AsReadOnly()`).

Comment: and Paolo, use the `\`` backtick to wrap inline code, particularly when generics are involved.

Comment: @Paulo and Anthony: Score, thanks for inserting them back, didn't know how to do it, and I didn't want to look like a fool, so I quickly edited them to squares, you know how it is :)

Comment: it took my dim mind a few tries but I get it now :) Thank you, I understand why this will not work. Luckily refactoring out this interface should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do that with a list either. The compiler still cannot convert the types. You need to use a generic method. See code below:

```
class Test
{
    void DoTest()
    {
        MonitoredList<IInterface> mlist1 = new MonitoredList<Inherited>(); //Error
        MonitoredList<Inherited> mlist2 = new MonitoredList<Inherited>();
        DoSomething1(mlist2); //Error converting MonitoredList<Inherited> to MonitoredList<IInterface>

        MonitoredList<IInterface> list1 = new MonitoredList<Inherited>(); //Error
        MonitoredList<Inherited> list2 = new MonitoredList<Inherited>();
        DoSomething2(list2); //Error converting List<Inherited> to List<IInterface>

        DoSomething3<Inherited>(mlist2); //Works fine
        DoSomething3(mlist2); //<Inherited> is redundant
    }

    void DoSomething1(List<IInterface> list)
    { }

    void DoSomething2(MonitoredList<IInterface> list)
    { }

    //Generic method
    void DoSomething3<T>(MonitoredList<T> list) where T : IInterface
    { }
}

interface IInterface { }

class Inherited : IInterface { }

class MonitoredList<T> { }
```

Comment: Thank you for trying that out, as a result I realised I made a mistake in my question. I am trying to create an interface for my collection and see if I can use that as I used IEnumerable before.

Comment: No problem :). It seems your question was answered now though.